# Simple SQL in SSMS for linked-SAP-B1-HANA server returns blank rows

Tags: sql-server, hana, linked-server

I created a linked server connection to our SAP B1 HANA server in my SSMS environment and have been using it for various queries for a while - never had any issues. This week I typed in this simple query into SSMS:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY([LINKEDSERVERCONNECTION], 'SELECT T0."ItemCode", T0."UserText" FROM DATABASE.OITM T0;')
```

What I got was 99% blank cells with a seemingly random few cells with actual ItemCodes. I can see the corresponding number of rows as we have ItemCodes in our HANA database but where there should be the ItemCodes I see blanks. See following screenshot.

[image: results]

The column UserText **IS** showing properly though - when I scroll through I can recognize values but the corresponding ItemCode is blank when it should be the correct part number.

Now when I remove T0."UserText" from the query then all the ItemCodes show up fine. See screenshot.

[image: results]

So it seems that adding T0."UserText" to the query causes some strange problem returning data.

While few ItemCodes have something in UserText compared to all the other ItemCodes, those that do have data can sometimes have quite lengthy strings in UserText (sometimes 100+ characters). However, I do not believe there are enough instances of this to cause what I would believe to be a shortage of resources on the HANA server - but then I'm not a HANA systems expert.

If I query ItemCode and UserText in SAP B1's Query Wizard, I can get everything to display correctly. I need it to work in SSMS however.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing SSMS' troubles displaying the query with UserText?

Comment: if you try with  SELECT T0.[ItemCode], T0.[UserText] FROM DATABASE.OITM T0   ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea but HANA requires the column names to be enclosed in double quotes...

Comment: Could you maybe provide the `OPENQUERY` function?

Comment: The statement seems correct to me maybe he is mismatching somewhere? Have you tried with a where T0.ItemCode IS NOT NULL?